# This app is incompatible - on installing apk build on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk

When I run my game through Unity Remote 5 it works well, but when I build the apk and try to install it on my device, it shows app is incompatible, I have tried changing many settings in player settings section but nothing worked for me. What can be done with this problem?
I am using unity 2017.3, the Android version on phone is 7.0 (Nougat) (I also tried on oreo but didn't work either), minsdk version in player settings is set on the marshmallow and target SDK version is on highest installed.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What version of unity, what settings you have, and most important of all, what device you have problem on.

Comment: I have edited the question. I think the problem is not with the phone that I am using since the apk is incompatible with all of the phones that I have tried so far.

Comment: Install the apk via adb, it will give you the detail of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before. Maybe you can try removing the app you just have installed and trying to install the new version.

But you should complete your question with more information as someone comented.

Hope it works!

Comment: I have experienced that if I have the app already installed something similar happen, I second you try to uninstall it if you have it on your phone.

Comment: Also check the Android minimum version is ok in PlayerSettings